# Local image search?

Tags: windows, images

Im a big fan of the [Google Image Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en) to find similar images for an uploaded image.

Today I would have loved a similar functionality for my local (Windows 10) hard disk:

1. Start a local Windows program
2. Select a file from my local disk
3. Click "Search"
4. The Tool then searches my whole hard disk for similar images and displays them in a list, ordered by relevance.

**My question:**

Is such a tool available?

*(I'm aware of [Similar Images Finder](https://similarimagesfinder.codeplex.com/) which looks unpolished to me)*

**Update 1:**

The Similar Images Finder tries to compare every image with every other image ("m*n"). What I'm looking for is to only match *one* image against other images.

Comment: Could you please detail a bit more what features Similar Images Finder is lacking?

Comment: Must it be free, or do you have a budget?

Comment: @Mawg Money doesn't matter ;-)